# Number of action of symmetric group such that surjective property is maintained.

Tags: group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups

Consider the conjugation action of $S_n$ on an $n$ elements subset of itself.

How many actions are possible such that surjective property is maintained on the $n$ element subset of $S_n.$

Let the $n$ elements subset be denoted as $X_n.$

Seems two equivalent approaches:

left application of conjugate action on $X_n,$

Or, equivalently right application of conjugate action on $X_n.$

Let, $\tau$ be subset of $S_n$ and gets as result of its action on $X_n,$ get permutation $\sigma.$

Taking first interpretation,
$\sigma = \tau(abc)\tau^{-1}.$
But, seems confusing as $\tau$ is unknown.
Next, second interpretation.
$\sigma = (bac)\tau(abc).$
But, even that doesn't help as nothing else is known about $\sigma, \tau.$

---

Edit: There will be three fixed points, in composition of three permutations:
$\tau(abc)\tau^{-1}.$

Taking a particular example of $S_6$ and $a,b,c= 1,2,3:$

Let $$\tau=\begin{pmatrix} 4&1& 5& 3&2&6\\ 
1& 5& 3& 2& 6& 4\\
\end{pmatrix}$$
then, $$\tau^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix} 1&5& 3& 2&6&4\\ 
4& 1& 5& 3& 2& 6\\
\end{pmatrix}.$$
Then $$(123)\tau^{-1}= \begin{pmatrix} 1&5& 3& 2&6&4\\ 
4& 2& 5& 1& 3& 6\\
\end{pmatrix},$$
Then, $$\tau(123)\tau^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix} 1&5& 3& 2&6&4\\ 
1& 6& 3& 5& 2& 4\\
\end{pmatrix},$$

But, how to prove there will always be three fixed points, and the rest are in a cycle?

The fixed points in $\tau(123)\tau^{-1}$ are all those elements in $\tau^{-1}$ not having map (co-domain) in $\{1,2,3\}$; as the map is changed for others in $(123)\tau^{-1}$ to not yield fixed point after composition from left by $\tau$.

Comment: Any $3$-cycle $(a b c)$ is a conjugate of $(1 2 3)$ (in the "first interpretation") because you can take $\tau: 1\to a, 2\to b, 3\to c$. Use elementary combinatorics to find how many of those $3$-cycles exist.

Comment: @StinkingBishop Can you please elaborate why you consider $\tau\in S_6$ to be a $3$-cycle.

Comment: $(1 2 3)$ is a $3$-cycle. $\tau$ can be anything but $\sigma$ will end up being another $3$-cycle $(\tau(1) \tau(2) \tau(3))$. The bigger picture: in $S_n$ conjugation of course transposes the elements of $[n]$ but keeps the structure of the permutation (i.e. breakdown into cycles) intact. A $k$-cycle maps into another $k$-cycle.

Comment: @StinkingBishop You mean conjugation action will lead to three fixed points in $\sigma.$

Comment: Well, yes, equivalently. $(1 2 3)$ strictly speaking means "$1$ goes to $2$, $2$ goes to $3$, $3$ goes to $1$ and everything else is fixed". The conjugate will have some other three elements such that first goes to second, second to third, third to first, and everything else will be fixed.

Comment: But I think it is more helpful to look at the cycles rather than the number of elements fixed. Say, in $S_6$ you can have two elements fixed via two different ways: by having a $4$-cycle (e.g. $(1 2 3 4)$) or by having two $2$-cycles (e.g. $(1 2)(3 4)$).

Comment: @StinkingBishop Let $\tau = (415326)\implies \tau^{-1}= (623514),$ then $(415326)(123)(623514).$
$$\tau=\begin{pmatrix} 4&1& 5& 3&2&6\\ 
1& 5& 3& 2& 6& 4\\
\end{pmatrix},$$
$$\tau^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix} 6&2& 3& 5&1&4\\ 
2& 3& 5& 1& 4& 6\\
\end{pmatrix}.$$

Then, $$(415326)(123)(623514)=$$
$$\tau(123)\tau^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix} 6&2& 3& 5&1&4\\ 
2& 5& 3& 6& 1& 4\\
\end{pmatrix} =
(625).$$
But, better way to state is: there are $3!$ values.

Comment: Correct, although $\tau$ itself doesn't need to be a cycle. (It would work with any $\tau$.) As for $3!$, what do you mean?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138056/discussion-between-jiten-and-stinking-bishop).

Comment: @StinkingBishop You stated: Use elementary combinatorics to find how many of those 3-cycles exist. So, interpreted as $3!,$ given by: $e, (123), (12), (13), (23), (132).$

Comment: $(12)$ is a $2$-cycle. A $3$ cycle is, e.g. $(6 2 5)$ you saw before. Which is incidentally the same permutation as $(2 5 6)$ and $(5 6 2)$.

Comment: @StinkingBishop Answer should be then: taking any $3$ positions out of $6$, such that they form a cycle. But, don't know how to derive formula of $6C3.2$?

Comment: @StinkingBishop Seems got idea. First choose which $3$ are selected by $6C3$, then multiply by $2!$ ways  similar to chances available of seating $3$ people around a round table.

Comment: Yep. Or, have $6\cdot 5\cdot 4$ *ordered* selections, then divide that by $3$ (as triplets of selections give you the same cycle). In general, for a group of $n$ elements, and $k$-cycles, the number is $n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-k+1)/k$.

Comment: @StinkingBishop Why elements with the same cycle type are conjugate? Also, what is : cycle type.

Comment: Kindly see the edited post.

Comment: I am sorry, but I am not sure I can help much more. This is something that is best covered in a textbook, with precise definitions and full proofs. Have a look at some Internet resources, for example https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Cycle_type_of_a_permutation. (In fact, type "**permutations cycle type**" into Google - lots of resources will pop up!)  It should also be covered in most introductory courses in group theory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conjugate elements of $S_n$ have the same cycle type. Conversely,  elements with the same cycle type are conjugate.

So it's a matter of counting the number of $3$ cycles $\sigma $.

In $S_6$, there's $6\cdot 5\cdot 4/3=40$ three cycles.

Comment: But, can you please elaborate- the first line: "...have the same cycle type. " Also, please point errors in my last comment above.

Comment: Why not try to think it through, jiten, instead of insisting on others doing your work for you?

Comment: @GerryMyerson It was difficult to assume how the converse is true. There could be many, not clear about : "the same cycle type."